# Query on Apache load balancer balancer-manager and also on JSESSIONID/Stickysessions

Tags: apache-2.4, load-balancing, mod-proxy, sticky-sessions

I am setting up Apache with mod_proxy and balancer-manager, and just have two questions on this.

1 Is there any way to color code the status in the balancer-manager? EG green for OK, blue for draining, red for disabled, or something like it? A stpuid question I know, but I find visual aids like colors help.

2 Using JSESSIONID sticky sessions. If I restart the apache load balancer in front, will this reset the users JSESSIONID?

Regards
B

Answer (score 0):

1) No. You'd have to make an RFE or modify the code yourself.

2) No, it should have no effect. Apache addes 'routes' to the end of the JSESSIONID that is set by the underlying app server and uses this route when requests are made to determine which underlying service to use.